# Css vertical-align for spans inside div have height auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with css.
I have one div and 3 columns inside it span, h3 and span.
I wants:
    div {height: auto} //auto change by content in h3
    h3 {height: auto} //this height will be change by content.
    span {vertical-align: middle}

```
<div>
   <span>span 1</span>
   <h3>text</h3>
   <span>span 2</span>
</div>
```

Please help me to style it.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you done to solve this? Seems like you want us to answer your homework or something....

Comment: Why is this tagged "javascript"?

Comment: @Todd, I think, the people use "javascript" maybe use Css. So it it is a inconvenience, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div > * {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>span 1</span>
  <h3>text <br />text</h3>
  <span>span 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @MonteCristo, can I set min-height and vertical-align for h3 tag, I try but It is not working?

Comment: @Sophia no you can't by default cell minimum height is the height of the content... it behaves like a table cell... HOWEVER, you can set "height" which will influence the height of the cell... I've update it for you...

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout > "In CSS 2.1, the height of a cell box is the minimum height required by the content. The table cell's 'height' property can influence the height of the row (see above), but it does not increase the height of the cell box."

Answer (score 0):

Simple... use this.

```css
div {height: 200px;}
span, h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <span>span 1</span>
   <h3>text</h3>
   <span>span 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Would this make both the `span`'s overlap each other?

Comment: no, why would it do that? If they were absolutely positioned it would.

Comment: lol opps my bad. For some reason I was thinking they were all stacked block level elements.

Comment: ha no problem, it would help if the OP put some of the css that was used, but it does say columns.

Comment: Currently, I have 3 tags is 3 rows, and I need they are changed to 3 columns, and then span's content always vertical-align when h3's height is changed.

Comment: @Sophia did you try the CSS above for the `span, h3 {}`??

Comment: @Aaron, Yes, I try css for them but it not working. I need the div and h3 with height auto.